# Adding anaconda path to .bashrc running on Redhat 7 breaks x2go login

Tags: rhel, path, bashrc, x2go

I am using x2go to connect to a remote Redhat 7 server running the MATE desktop. The problem I am having is when I add `export PATH="/opt/apps/anaconda2/5.0.1/bin:$PATH"` to my .bashrc it completely breaks my ability to login with x2go. However, if I am on site I can login to the system just fine at the server's console using the MATE desktop.

The reason I need to have `export PATH="/opt/apps/anaconda2/5.0.1/bin:$PATH"` in my .bashrc is so when I run `which python` I get `/opt/apps/anaconda2/5.0.1/bin` which is my desired version of python and not `/usr/bin/python` which is the systems default version of python.

The problem seems to be specific to x2go not liking `export PATH="/opt/apps/anaconda2/5.0.1/bin:$PATH"` in my .bashrc. Is it possible to make this work?

Here are the x2go error messages.

[image]

Here are some logs form /var/log/messages to accompany the error above

```
 
Mar 28 10:08:58 mv-dev-rhel7-clone systemd-logind: New session 106 of user scott.
Mar 28 10:08:58 mv-dev-rhel7-clone systemd: Started Session 106 of user scott.
Mar 28 10:08:58 mv-dev-rhel7-clone systemd: Starting Session 106 of user scott.
Mar 28 10:09:03 mv-dev-rhel7-clone /usr/sbin/x2gocleansessions[981]: scott-50-1522246141_stDMATE_dp32: state file for this session does not exist: /tmp/.x2go-scott/C-scott-50-1522246141_stDMATE_dp32/state (this can be ignored during session startups)
Mar 28 10:09:03 mv-dev-rhel7-clone /usr/bin/x2gostartagent: successfully started X2Go agent session with ID scott-50-1522246141_stDMATE_dp32
Mar 28 10:09:06 mv-dev-rhel7-clone /usr/bin/x2gomountdirs[85085]: successfully mounted scott@127.0.0.1:35193/Users/scott/.x2go/S-scott-50-1522246141_stDMATE_dp32/spool to /tmp/.x2go-scott/spool/C-scott-50-1522246141_stDMATE_dp32
Mar 28 10:09:07 mv-dev-rhel7-clone /usr/bin/x2goruncommand: launching session with Xsession-x2go mechanism, using STARTUP="mate-session"
Mar 28 10:09:09 mv-dev-rhel7-clone mate-session[85249]: WARNING: Could not make bus activated clients aware of XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=MATE environment variable: Could not connect: Connection refused
Mar 28 10:09:09 mv-dev-rhel7-clone mate-session[85249]: WARNING: Could not make bus activated clients aware of DISPLAY=:50 environment variable: Could not connect: Connection refused
Mar 28 10:09:09 mv-dev-rhel7-clone mate-session[85249]: WARNING: Could not make bus activated clients aware of MATE_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated environment variable: Could not connect: Connection refused
Mar 28 10:09:09 mv-dev-rhel7-clone mate-session[85249]: dconf-WARNING: failed to commit changes to dconf: Could not connect: Connection refused
Mar 28 10:09:09 mv-dev-rhel7-clone mate-session[85249]: WARNING: Could not make bus activated clients aware of SESSION_MANAGER=local/unix:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/85249,unix/unix:/tmp/.ICE-unix/85249 environment variable: Could not connect: Connection refused
Mar 28 10:09:15 mv-dev-rhel7-clone mate-session[85249]: Gtk-CRITICAL: gtk_main_quit: assertion 'main_loops != NULL' failed
Mar 28 10:09:15 mv-dev-rhel7-clone mate-session[85249]: CRITICAL: dbus_g_proxy_new_for_name: assertion 'connection != NULL' failed
Mar 28 10:09:16 mv-dev-rhel7-clone mate-session[85249]: Gtk-CRITICAL: gtk_main_quit: assertion 'main_loops != NULL' failed
Mar 28 10:09:16 mv-dev-rhel7-clone mate-session[85249]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Mar 28 10:09:16 mv-dev-rhel7-clone gnome-keyring-daemon[85468]: couldn't access control socket: /run/user/1000/keyring/control: No such file or directory
Mar 28 10:09:16 mv-dev-rhel7-clone gnome-keyring-daemon[85468]: couldn't connect to dbus session bus: Could not connect: Connection refused
Mar 28 10:09:16 mv-dev-rhel7-clone gnome-keyring-daemon[85468]: couldn't connect to dbus session bus: Could not connect: Connection refused
Mar 28 10:09:16 mv-dev-rhel7-clone gnome-keyring-daemon[85468]: couldn't connect to dbus session bus: Could not connect: Connection refused
Mar 28 10:09:16 mv-dev-rhel7-clone mate-session[85249]: WARNING: Could not make bus activated clients aware of GTK_OVERLAY_SCROLLING=0 environment variable: Could not connect: Connection refused
Mar 28 10:09:16 mv-dev-rhel7-clone mate-session[85249]: WARNING: keycode1 not existent
Mar 28 10:09:16 mv-dev-rhel7-clone mate-session[85249]: WARNING: keycode2 not existent
Mar 28 10:09:16 mv-dev-rhel7-clone mate-session[85249]: WARNING: GSIdleMonitor: IDLETIME counter not found
Mar 28 10:09:16 mv-dev-rhel7-clone mate-session[85249]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: object GSIdleMonitor 0xa5fd20 finalized while still in-construction
Mar 28 10:09:16 mv-dev-rhel7-clone mate-session[85249]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: Custom constructor for class GSIdleMonitor returned NULL (which is invalid). Please use GInitable instead.
Mar 28 10:09:16 mv-dev-rhel7-clone mate-session[85249]: CRITICAL: error getting session bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-1aBwJG1rzI: Connection refused
Mar 28 10:09:16 mv-dev-rhel7-clone mate-session[85249]: WARNING: Unable to register presence with session bus
Mar 28 10:09:16 mv-dev-rhel7-clone mate-session[85249]: CRITICAL: dbus_g_proxy_new_for_name: assertion 'connection != NULL' failed
Mar 28 10:09:16 mv-dev-rhel7-clone mate-session[85249]: CRITICAL: error getting session bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-1aBwJG1rzI: Connection refused
Mar 28 10:09:17 mv-dev-rhel7-clone /usr/bin/x2goumount-session[85540]: successfully unmounted "/tmp/.x2go-scott/spool/C-scott-50-1522246141_stDMATE_dp32"
Mar 28 10:09:38 mv-dev-rhel7-clone /usr/sbin/x2gocleansessions[981]: scott-50-1522246141_stDMATE_dp32: found stale X-server process (84761), sending SIGKILL
```

Comment: Maybe there is a command name collision? Try `PATH="$PATH:/opt/apps/anaconda2/5.0.1/bin"`; no need to export; `$PATH` is already exported.

Comment: This does allow me to login via x2go. Unfortunately, when I run `which python` I see the system's standard python installation located in `/usr/bin/python` and not `/opt/apps/anaconda2/5.0.1/bin/python` which is the intended result and will not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to update to the most recent version of x2goserver on the serverside with `yum update x2goserver`. I know, I know, but in my defense the first thing I did was check for updates, but there was not any updates at the time.

Bad  version of `x2goserver version 4.0.1.20`

Good version of `x2goserver version 4.0.1.22`

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, even using the latest versions of x2goserver as listed in the last answer.

It seems that anaconda ships with its own version of the dbus tools that x2goserver relies upon, in particular dbus-run-session and dbus-launch. Adding the anaconda directory to the path causes x2goserver to pick up the anaconda versions rather than those that shipped with the distro (Centos 7.5 in my case). I assume there is some sort of incompatibility between the versions.

Once I removed the dbus utilities from the anaconda directory, I could login again.